# MySQL - Delete rows after specific ID value.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to delete all rows from the table that are 60 before the latest ID value.

EG: If user1 posts a message that gets an ID of 100 then the message which has an ID of 40 will be deleted.

How would I do this? I need it to keep my table clean.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can give us a clear example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DELETE a.* FROM YourTable AS a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as MaxID FROM YourTable) AS b
ON a.id <= b.MaxID - 60;
```

Comment: if the table name is chat_chats would I just replace YourTable with chat_chats? id is correct.

Comment: Of course. That's just a placeholder, you put whatever the actual table name is.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is not properly clear, but I try to do some example:

1) Simple (delete all object before last id):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID < lastId;
```

2) Only ID of a specific user:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID < lastId and USERID = myUserID;
```

Previous object should have always minor ID number (if you use a autoincrement option).

Enjoy your code.